# trouble in contact name in listview

Tags: android

how to show all contact name in listview. please help me i tried

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);

    if(cur.getCount()>0)
    {
        int x=0;
        String name[] = null;
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cur.getString(
                                      cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            name[x]=  cur.getString(
                                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            x++;

            //Toast.makeText(this,id+"--"+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        ArrayAdapter arr = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);
        lv.setAdapter(arr);
    }
}
```

regards
arindom

Comment: If you write your problem properly with the logs then it will be easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is okay then problem is with your string array.You can't use string array like you used.Use like this instead

```
String name[] = new String[cur.getCount()];
```

Comment: thanks rasel now it's working but if i initialize to null so it didn't working

Comment: Yes i told you about that.Don't forget to upvote/accept an answer if it helps you